# How to start Iterm with spefic commands in specific panes?

Tags: terminal, command, autostart, iterm, pane

I know, that I can load a default arrangement with panes. But how can I run specific commands in specific panes on start?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open, split a iTerm2 window and execute commands inside each of those panes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56037312/open-split-a-iterm2-window-and-execute-commands-inside-each-of-those-panes)