# Open, split a iTerm2 window and execute commands inside each of those panes

Tags: macos, applescript, iterm2

I'm trying to create a script which would open a `iTerm2` window, split it into 3 panes vertically and run a few commands inside each of those panes.

Here's my attempt so far:

```
tell application "iTerm2"
  activate

  -- Create main window
  create window with default profile

  tell current session of current window
    set name to "frontend"
    write text "cd ~/Documents/frontendDir"
    split vertically with default profile
  end tell

  tell second session of current window -- ERROR HERE
    set name to "backend"
    write text "cd ~/Documents/backendDir"
    split vertically with default profile
  end tell

  tell third session of current window
    set name to "apollo-server"
    write text "cd ~/Documents/GitHub/apolloDir"
  end tell
end tell
```

The first part about creating the `frontend` seems to work as the window is correctly opened and the command `cd ~/Documents/frontendDir` is correctly executed in it. The window is also split vertically once as I'm pretty sure it stops executing when I try to access the second pane of my window.

I'm getting this error: `iTerm got an error: Can’t get session 2 of current window`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Applescript (osascript): opening split panes in iTerm 2 and performing commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22339250/applescript-osascript-opening-split-panes-in-iterm-2-and-performing-commands)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*iTerm* `session` objects are contained by `tabs`, not `windows`.  Therefore, as you can see in the script snippet below, I've referenced each session to write to by way of the `current tab` of the `current window`:

```
tell application "iTerm"
    activate

    set W to current window
    if W = missing value then set W to create window with default profile
    tell W's current session
        split vertically with default profile
        split vertically with default profile
    end tell
    set T to W's current tab
    write T's session 1 text "cd ~/Desktop"
    write T's session 2 text "cd ~/Downloads"
    write T's session 3 text "cd ~/Documents"
end tell
```

As far as I can tell, you cannot set the `name` property of a `session`; it gets set to the title of the session's frame.  You can reference each `session` either by its index (as I've done here); its `id` property; or its `tty` property; all of which are unique values.

As you can see, the index appears to be ordered by a session's creation:

[image: iTerm on macOS]

Answer (score 0):

You can use python script:

```
import iterm2

async def main(connection):
    app = await iterm2.async_get_app(connection)
    window = app.current_terminal_window

    # Define base path and project name variables
    base_path = '/Users/username/somefolder'
    project_name = 'projectname'

    if window is not None:
        # Create a new tab
        tab = await window.async_create_tab()
        
        # Store a reference to the left pane (initial session)
        left_panel = tab.current_session

        # Execute command in the top-left pane
        cmd_top_left = f'cd {base_path}; ./docker-{project_name}-run-kernel\n'
        await left_panel.async_send_text(cmd_top_left)

        # Create a right pane by splitting the left one vertically
        right_panel = await left_panel.async_split_pane(vertical=True)

        # Split the right pane into top and bottom panes
        bottom_right_panel = await right_panel.async_split_pane(vertical=False)

        # Execute command in the top-right pane
        cmd_top_right = f'cd {base_path}/{project_name}\n'
        await right_panel.async_send_text(cmd_top_right)

        # Execute command in the bottom-right pane
        cmd_bottom_right = f'docker exec -it {project_name}-puma-1 bash\n'
        await bottom_right_panel.async_send_text(cmd_bottom_right)

        # Split the left pane into top and bottom using the stored reference
        bottom_left_panel = await left_panel.async_split_pane(vertical=False)

        # Execute command in the bottom-left pane
        cmd_bottom_left = f'cd {base_path}; ./docker-{project_name}-run-rails; cd {base_path}/{project_name}\n'
        await bottom_left_panel.async_send_text(cmd_bottom_left)

    else:
        print("No current window")

iterm2.run_until_complete(main)
```

[image]