Is it possible to execute command in another split pane without leaving the current pane in iTerm2?
Using iTerm2 (Python API allowed), is it possible to execute command in another split pane without leaving the current pane?
Example Use-case:

I have two split panes.
In the first pane, I edit Rust source code in Vim.
In the second pane, I execute cargo test command.
I want to re-execute cargo test anytime I want without leaving the first pane.

Please note the example use-case above is just an example; I don't always use Vim or Rust.
In general, I want to do something in the first pane and do something in the first pane without leaving the first pane.
Current Workaround
My current workaround is incomplete and not specific to iTerm2:

I do something in the first pane.

In the second pane, I monitor changes made by the first pane and execute any command every time a change occurs using fswatch or entr.



Looks hopeful https://stackoverflow.com/a/56040443/2836621
